# Android scrollable table with fixed header, make dummy rows invisible

Tags: android, visibility, android-tablelayout, fixed-header-tables

I know there have been several posts about this, but I can't get this working. I want a table with a header that stays visible while scrolling through the contents of the table. I'm fond of this approach: http://www.entreotrascosas.net/creating-dynamic-scrollable-fixed-header-tables-in-android/

Here's my xml. I got two TableLayouts, one for the header and one for the contents. I filled them with one row each, with `layout_height` set to `0dp`.

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TableRow
       android:id="@+id/hiddenLongestRow"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="0dp"  />
</TableLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false" > 
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/hiddenHeaderRow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"  />     
    </TableLayout>   
</ScrollView>
```

I then programmatically fill the tables with my values and the rows specified in my xml with dummy values for the header / the longest row. Now, the columns of both tables have the same width. So far, so good.

But now I need the two dummy rows to disappear. It was said setting the height to `0dp` would do this, but for me it doesn't, the rows are always visible.

I tried setting the height of the LayoutParams to 0 programmatically, but it didn't help. Setting the visibility to INVISIBLE or GONE does not do the job. What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove it:

```
TableRow row = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.hiddenHeaderRow);
table.removeView(row);
```